# Apply styles to child element on parent hover (framer motion)?

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

i saw this code and i took a screenshot and tried it but it didnt work

is this even a thing or not ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When animation property (like `animate` or `whileHover`) defined as string (i.e. variant), it's value is 'propagated' to children by default. So you can define `variants` on children and `whileHover` on parent and framer motion will animate children when its parent is hovered. You can find more (with examples) in [framer motion documentation](https://www.framer.com/motion/animation/##propagation).

So, for example, if you want to animate `h2` when `section` is hovered you can do it like this:

```
const variants = {
    hover: { scale: 1.2 },
};

const Example = () => {
    return (<motion.section whileHover="hover">
        <motion.h2 variants={variants}>Title...</motion.h2>
        <motion.div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</motion.div>
    </motion.section>);
};
```